# 3D Perspective not showing correctly in Firefox 34.0 or Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, perspective

I'm having trouble getting this to display at all in internet explorer 11 and Firefox 34.0. I've double and triple checked prefixes and made sure there are values for everything.

If this doesn't work, I'll just have to find another solution that will work across browsers, but I've put a lot of work getting it just right for my site as it is.

**UPDATE:** I got it working on Firefox. It was a -moz prefix not added to the .pyramid-outer selector. Now, however, I'm getting lines above the pyramid in a "+" pattern. Is there a way to alleviate this? I also got it to show a simple triangle in IE 11, but I'm still unable to get it to preserve the 3D.

[Updated Screenshot in Firefox 34.0](http://u.cubeupload.com/srobbins33/ikglMA.png)

[Updated Screenshot in IE 11](http://u.cubeupload.com/srobbins33/A1LLL7.png)

```
.pyramid, .pyramid-outer, .pyramid-inner {
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.viewport {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
top: -200px;

-webkit-perspective: 1000px;
-moz-perspective: 1000px;
-o-perspective: 1000px;
perspective: 800px;

-webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 150%;
-moz-perspective-origin: 50% 150%;
-o-perspective-origin: 50% 150%;
-ms-perspective-origin: 50% 150%;
perspective-origin: 50% 150%;
}

.pyramid {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
/*-webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);*/
}

.pyramid-outer {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 250px, 400px) rotateX(-22deg);
}

.pyramid-base, .pyramid-face {
opacity: 0.5;
position: absolute;
}

.pyramid-base {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #ff0000;
background-image: url(http://romanliutikov.com/lab/css3-3d-primitives/img.png);

-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, -23px);
-moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, -23px);
-o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, -23px);
-ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, -23px);
transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, -23px);
}

.pyramid-face {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left:50px solid transparent;
border-right:50px solid transparent;

-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 87%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 87%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 87%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 87%;
transform-origin: 50% 87%;
}

.pyramid-face:nth-child(2) {
border-bottom:100px solid #e04545;

-webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
-moz-transform: rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
-o-transform: rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
-ms-transform: rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
transform: rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
}

.pyramid-face:nth-child(3) {
border-bottom:100px solid #FFFF99;

-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
-o-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
}

.pyramid-face:nth-child(4) {
border-bottom:100px solid #97c25f;

-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
-o-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
}

.pyramid-face:nth-child(5) {
border-bottom:100px solid #4ccfc8;

-webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
-moz-transform: rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
-o-transform: rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
-ms-transform: rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
transform: rotateX(-30deg) translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
}

.pyramid {
-webkit-animation: cube 8s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: cube 8s linear infinite;
-o-animation: cube 8s linear infinite;
animation: cube 8s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cube {
0% {}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);   }
}

@-o-keyframes cube {
0% {}
100% {-o-transform: rotateY(360deg);    }
}

@-ms-keyframes cube {
0% {}
100% {-ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);   }
}

@keyframes cube {
0% {}
100% {transform: rotateY(360deg);   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preserve 3D is only in beta in IE. It shouldn't work yet.

https://status.modern.ie/csstransformspreserve3d?term=preserve

Comment: I saw this on microsoft's website, but I don't know how to apply it correctly as I've tried: "Note:  The W3C specification defines a keyword value of preserve-3d for this property, which indicates that flattening is not performed. At this time, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the preserve-3d keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the child element's normal transform."

Comment: That note is disingenuous. The sophistication of the math required to reproduce the effect of preserve-3D is extremely high. It's not just a simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: Ah, well thanks for the help then. I've managed to get mixed results with different setups, but none of them even close to what I'm looking for.